# Greasemonkey - Looped Notification

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a site where an amount rises and i wanted to display a notification that only displays once the amount is more than 10.

I check every 2 seconds but now the notification keeps popping up on the screen.

How can i make a notification that displays once when the condition is met that stays visible until clicked?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  test
// @author       You
// @match        http://example.com*
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// @grant        GM_notification
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

var site_status = false;

function site_update(){

    var currentclaim = parseInt( document.evaluate('//*[@id="Amount"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML );

    if (currentclaim > 10) {
        site_status = true;
    }

    if (site_status) {
        GM_notification("Now Time", "It is now time" + currentclaim, null, 1000);
    }

    setTimeout(site_update, 2000);
}

site_update();

})();
```

Comment: The [parameters](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_notification) are incorrect. Specify an options object with timeout:0

Comment: Do you have a code example if possible.